# How should <button> be used? when it is NOT used as "submit" button

Tags: php, html, forms, button

How could I receive the value of the  element using PHP?

For example:

```
<button name="aButton" value="abcd">
```

note: I am NOT talking about using it as the submit button.

Comment: How have you tried so far?

Comment: Why assign a value to a button?

Comment: Are you saying press button receive abcd?

Comment: a form using get or post.

Comment: @Jason - I have tried this:

<?php echo $_POST["aButton"]; ?> but it returns blank.

Comment: People be gentle on OP. He's obviously trying

Comment: Assigning values to Button's is quite common I though. To the op you need to close the button </button> plus set the button to type=submit. I'm assuming it's in a form?

Comment: @AhmadAlfy if you think these questions are not gentle you've clearly not seen a lot even for 7k rep :P

Comment: Can you show more of your code...The <form> bits, etc...?

Comment: @Doug, yes, I need a </button>. Omitted that because I am lazy to type it all. I am looking at scenario where it is not used as a form-submit button but rather just as a part of the form. Can I use it to capture say a selection? (instead of radio or checkbox)

Comment: i dont know if this will work but you could try type="hidden" inside the button code

Comment: @jason he said he does NOT want it to be a submit button so please remove that flag

Comment: @jason, also, I have tried something like $value = $_POST['obrf']; as you referred, the return value is empty.

Comment: This Works: <button > <input type="hidden" name="aButton" value="why you no let me answer this question" /></button>

Comment: ha - whats funny is if you have the button and a separate submit button - and you click on the button only - it submits the form. buttons b greedy.

Comment: @Matt I assumed OP is asking a novice question but it turned out I was mistaken. Check my answer below, I am the noob here.

Answer (score -1):

Change button to input type="submit" and then,

Assuming you are submitting the form via POST - You can simple access it's value using:

`$_POST['aButton']`

Comment: Thanks Andrea but I am not trying to use it as Submit but more like radio or checkbox. Or would that be considered improper use?

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is the `input` element. It is used like this:

`<input type="submit" value="whatever" />`

This will behave exactly like a button and will submit your form. Buttons <strike>cannot have the value attribute</strike> **actually they can**. Thanks to [Json](https://stackoverflow.com/users/99401/jason) for pointing that out in the comments, I had no idea that it is a valid attribute.

According to the [W3C Working Draft on HTML5](http://A%20button%20(and%20its%20value)%20is%20only%20included%20in%20the%20form%20submission%20if%20the%20button%20itself%20was%20used%20to%20initiate%20the%20form%20submission.); the value of the button is only submitted when the button is used to initiate the form submission

> A button (and its value) is only included in the form submission if
>   the button itself was used to initiate the form submission.

Comment: Actually value is allowed in a button element, see https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/button#HTML_Attributes

Comment: I am aware of using input submit, but I am trying to use button as a form element like radio or checkbox.

Comment: @jason thank you I didn't know that it can be used. Further notes on the HTML5 working drafy https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#attr-button-value